# Editing R plotly axis labels in radar chart

Tags: r, plotly, radar-chart

I am trying to edit the axis of a `plotly` radar chart.
The following code produces [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udPTq.png).
Now I would like to add a percentage sign to the horizontal axis so that it says "0% 1% 2% 3% 4% 5%" instead of just the numbers?
How do I manage to do that?
Unfortunately, I do not really get along with [the documentation](https://plotly.com/r/reference/scatterpolar/) with regard to changing the x axis.

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "scatterpolar",
  fill = "toself",
  mode = "lines+markers"
)
for (i in 1:3) {
  d1 <- d %>% filter(Region %in% regions[i])
  fig <- fig %>%
    add_trace(
      r = d1 %>% slice(1:3, 1) %>% pull(Wachstum),
      theta = d1 %>% slice(1:3, 1) %>% pull(Bezeichnung),
      name = d1 %>% slice(1) %>% pull(Region),
      hovertemplate = paste0(
        "%{fullData.name}<br>",
        "%{theta}<br>",
        "Wachstum: %{r:.3} %",
        "<extra></extra>"
      )
    )
}
fig
```

On a related note, how would I edit the axis [in the following case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTIJV.png): I would like to change the "M" on the horizontal axis to "Mio." so that it says "0 0.2Mio. 0.4Mio." and so on?

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "scatterpolar",
  fill = "toself",
  mode = "lines+markers"
)
for (i in 1:3) {
  d1 <- d %>% filter(Region %in% regions[i])
  fig <- fig %>%
    add_trace(
      r = d1 %>% slice(1:3, 1) %>% pull(Wert),
      theta = d1 %>% slice(1:3, 1) %>% pull(Bezeichnung),
      name = d1 %>% slice(1) %>% pull(Region),
      hovertemplate = paste0(
        "%{fullData.name}<br>",
        "%{theta}<br>",
        "Wert: %{r:}",
        "<extra></extra>"
      )
    )
}
fig
```

My data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
d <- structure(
  list(
    Region = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C",
               "C", "C"),
    Bezeichnung = c(
      "Agriculture",
      "Industry",
      "Services",
      "Agriculture",
      "Industry",
      "Services",
      "Agriculture",
      "Industry",
      "Services"
    ),
    Diff = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L),
    Wachstum = c(5,
                 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4),
    Wert = c(
      1322956.10582307,
      1362979.06356215,
      352138.918156773,
      340230.355633795,
      83354.3466503918,
      1476435.89480847,
      1321136.99315399,
      388579.265012443,
      715511.4116247
    )
  ),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-9L)
)
regions <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, to show the radial axis as percentages (which is what I think you are asking), you have to use `layout.polar.radialaxis.ticksuffix`.

```
fig %>% layout(polar = list(
  radialaxis = list(ticksuffix = '%')))
```

[image]

To format change the abbreviation from `M` for Millions to `Mio` for Millionen, you have a few options. The first thing I tried was setting the locale to Deutschland, but that didn't work. (It was still `M`.)

You could set the suffix, but the 0 would be `0io`, which doesn't make sense. In the end, I specifically designated all of the values you see and what they represent.

I initially used `seq`, but it doesn't use a trailing zero; I didn't like how it turned out.

```
fig %>% layout(polar = list(radialaxis = list(
  tickmode = "array",
  tickvals = seq(0, 1400000, by = 200000),
  ticktext = paste0(seq(0, 1.4, by = .2), "Mio")
)))
```

[image]

```
fig %>% layout(polar = list(radialaxis = list(
  tickmode = "array",
  tickvals = c(0, 200000, 400000, 600000, 800000, 1000000, 1200000, 1400000),
  ticktext = c("0", "0.2Mio", "0.4Mio", "0.6Mio", "0.8Mio", "1.0Mio", "1.2Mio", "1.4Mio")
)))
```

[image]